# sqlplus Not showing up after oracle installation

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am new to databases. I installed oracle on my centos 7 machine. After successfull installation I am getting "sqlite3" but not "sqlplus". Can someone let me know why "sqlplus" utility isn't came of its own and how I can get it.

CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

Package : linuxx64_12201_database.zip

Comment: What do you mean by *I am getting "sqlite3"*

Answer (score 1):

Your sqlplus program is under $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus . When you installed Oracle, you must have to select an ORACLE_HOME. If you use the one by default, probably it would be some like ( see below ).

Ensure that the environment variables ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID are set properly. The commands to use to set these environment variables depend on the shell you use to interface with the operating system. For example ( bash ):

```
export ORACLE_SID=xxxxxx # where xxxxx is the name of the database sid

export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2/dbhome_1 # example by default 

export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

# Once you execute these commands, you can run sqlplus 

sqlplus user/pwd
```

Comment: I performed the steps as you said no luck. However I installed sqlplus instant client but not able to connect through oracle user cresential.

Comment: [oracle@nagios-server root]$ export ORACLE_SID=orcl

[oracle@nagios-server root]$ export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1

[oracle@nagios-server root]$ export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

Comment: [oracle@nagios-server root]$ sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Jun 24 12:27:01 2020
Version 19.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: oracle
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist


Enter user-name:

Comment: Hi @AmanSingh . can you run these commands:   ps -ef | grep pmon

Comment: and ps -ef | grep tns

Comment: [oracle@oracle-server root]$ ps -ef | grep pmon
oracle   15870     1  0 02:35 ?        00:00:00 ora_pmon_orcl
oracle   32300 31956  0 03:21 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pmon

Comment: [oracle@oracle-server root]$ ps -ef | grep tns
root        14     2  0 00:35 ?        00:00:00 [netns]
oracle   32293 31956  0 03:21 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto tns

Comment: Hi @AmanSingh, you have no listener configured. You must create a listener.ora file and start the listener in the database

Comment: Can you please provide me the steps or any reference link? Where should I create the listener.ora file and its content?

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-network-configuration

Comment: Hi @AmanSingh  I would appreciate if you accept the answer to your quesiton